# Print List to console in Table format

Tags: freemarker

I'm looking for a Freemarker template that can output a List to console in tabular format.

```
<#list ["foo", "bar", "baz", "huhu", "lala", "keke", "koko", "fifi", "bubu"] as x>
${x}
</#list>
```

I'm looking for console output like:

```
foo      bar      baz
huhu     lala     keke
koko     fifi     bubu
```

I think `${x?item_cycle('col1', 'col2', 'col3')}` maybe the way to go, adding a line break only for `col3` items. But how can I do if else logic on item_cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nicest way of adding line breaks is probably with `?chunk(n)`. Also, the column width (which you haven't asked about) can for example be ensured with `?right_pad(n)`. So the example is:

```
<#list ["foo", "bar", "baz", "huhu", "lala", "keke", "koko", "fifi", "bubu"]?chunk(3) as row>
  <#list row as x>${x?right_pad(10)}</#list>
</#list>
```

BTW, as you have asked, of course you can write things like `<#if x?item_cycle(...) == ...>`, or even `${x}${x?item_cycle('', '', '\n')}`, or `<#if x?item_count % 3 == 0>`, but these are uglier solutions.

Comment: Great that works. Any idea how I can get the index of the cell `x`. I tried `${x?counter}` but that just returns the row number.

Comment: Figured it out. Create variable <#assign y++>